# Ubuntu cron job

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I wrote a bash script I saved it as a file getcalls.sh, I used chmod+x on the file to make it executable. It curls csv output from an api into a file in the same directory it runs in. It runs in a directory called data in one of my web folders. When I run it from command line it runs fine. When I try to put it in cron it doesn't run. My cron entry looks like this.

```
12 03 * * 3 cd /var/www/html/sitedir/data/getcalls.sh
```

Is the syntax incorrect?

Comment: ok. It was directly related to the data import of a website but I will ask somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your syntax is incorrect. You must use it this way:

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command
```

But you provide `cd` command. Use it as follows:

```
12 03 * * 3 /var/www/html/sitedir/data/getcalls.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. The cd was a typo from a bad cut and paste and I was too tired to see it.